# rails link_to_function help understanding

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to maintain some quite old Rails code (not written by me), and struggling badly with some non-functional javascript that I can't get working.

It uses the link_to_function call which I see has been deprecated, and I was wondering what people use as a replacement.

This is the code I'm trying to fix:

```
link_to_function text, :class => "button new add_track" do |page|
  track = render(:partial => 'track', :locals => { :f => form, :track => Track.new })
  page << ""+
    "var new_track_id = \"new_\" + new Date().getTime();"+
    "$('.track_list').append(\"#{ escape_javascript track }\".replace(/new_\\d+/g, new_track_id) );"+
    "tentracks.admin.ui.set_track_sort_order();"+
    "tentracks.admin.ui.setup_track_image_managers();"
end
```

I understand essentially that what's meant to happen is that the user clicks a link, which then appends the partial 'track' form onto the page, but I don't see how this is meant to work with the function 'link_to_function'.

From the API docs, I see a message signature of:

- 3.1.0 = link_to_function(name, function, html_options={})
- 2.2.1 = link_to_function(name, *args, &block)

Now I'm not 100% sure which this code was written against, but neither make much sense to me, in the code I've got, I can only see 2 arguments:

- Arg1 = 'text',
- Arg2 = ':class => "button....

I see no other commas to indicate arg 3.

There must be something I'm not understanding about Rails though because this code did used to work fine!

What would people recommend as how to add a form dynamically to a page in Rails using JS?

If anyone could explain what's happening in this code, that would be also v useful, as I think there's some fundamental part of Rails dev that's currently stopping me from understanding how to do simple things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the details you gave, I'm betting the code was written with Rails 2.2.x since the `link_to_function` still accepts a block.  I remember having to override the helper in rails 3 to accept a block.

There are 2 solutions to this.  The first one is to just place all the js in one long line.

```
track = render(:partial => 'track', :locals => { :f => form, :track => Track.new })
js = "var new_track_id = \"new_\" + new Date().getTime();$('.track_list').append(\"#{ escape_javascript track }\".replace(/new_\\d+/g, new_track_id) );tentracks.admin.ui.set_track_sort_order();tentracks.admin.ui.setup_track_image_managers();"

link_to_function text, js, :class => 'button new add_track'
```

That is the ugly solution.

With Rails 3, obstrusive javascripts like this one have been discouraged.  This is how you should write it.

```
link_to text, '', :class => 'button new add_track'

<script type='text/javascript'>
  $('.add_track').click(function() {
    var new_track_id = "new_" + new Date().getTime()

    $('.track_list').append("#{escape_javascript render('track', :f => form, :track => Track.new)}".replace(/new_\\d+/g, new_track_id))

    tentracks.admin.ui.set_track_sort_order()
    tentracks.admin.ui.setup_track_image_managers()
  })
</script>
```

Comment: I spent quite a long time (and didn't manage) trying to implement the 'good' way, but I hit numerous problems. They come under a different question really, so I'll do some more research and ask them on another post if required.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this structure:

```
do |page|
  ...
end
```

That is a block. So the method has the signature of a Rails 2.2.1 `link_to_function` method.

If someone clicks on the link, the javascript inside the block is evaluated. In a more up-to-date Rails version I would expect this to be done completely in Javascript by binding to a link's css class.